# Detect when user presses the red X in toolbar (top right)

Tags: c#, wpf, toolbar

Within the application I am writing for testing/learning C#, I use the hidden/visible property to open and close windows.
It is a WPF application.

In the main window, I have a "close" button that triggers this method:

```
public void buttonQuit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var message = exitmessage;
    var title = exitTitle;
    var result = MessageBox.Show(
        message,                    // the message to show
        title,                      // the title for the dialog box
        MessageBoxButton.YesNo,     // show two buttons: Yes and No
        MessageBoxImage.Question);  // show a question mark icon

    // lets see what has been pressed
    switch (result)
    {

        case System.Windows.MessageBoxResult.Yes:   // Yes button pressed
            CloseAllWindows();
            break;

        case System.Windows.MessageBoxResult.No:    // No button pressed
            break;

        default:                 // Neither Yes nor No pressed (just in case)
            MessageBox.Show("Oh noes! What did you press?!?!");
            break;
    }
}
```

This way I make sure that all windows get closed, including the hidden ones.
But now is the catch; when the user presses (in the main window) the top right red X in toolbar to close, only that main window gets closed, but in the background the hidden ones are still there.

So in fact it is 2 questions:

1. Is `CloseAllWindows();` really sufficient to get the app 100% closed down?
2. How do I "catch" the event when the user presses that red X in the toolbar, and make this also trigger the right closing event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be handling either the [`Closing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closing.aspx) or [`Closed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closed.aspx) event for your window(s). The former allows you to *cancel* the close, while the latter just allows you to perform necessary cleanup in response to the window being closed.

So, in this case, you should place the code from your `buttonQuit_Click` method into a handler method attached to the `Closing` event so that it gets triggered regardless of how the window is closed.

Then, your `buttonQuit_Click` method can simply call the window's [`Close` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.close.aspx). That will close the window, in turn raising the `Closing` event, and running your code in the attached handler method.

As far as your other question, `CloseAllWindows` will do exactly what it says: it will close all of the windows that your application has opened. In most cases, that *should* be sufficient to close the application, but it might not be, especially if you've created non-background threads or depending on the [`ShutdownMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode.aspx) setting.

[`App.Current.Shutdown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597013.aspx) will work unconditionally.

Comment: im not yet very deep into c# (just 2 weeks now hehe) so what exactly you mean with putting a method into a handler ?

Comment: by handler he means an Event Handler.. Closing or Closed are event delegates and you need to add a method delegate to handle the event..  I think its the best time you check this documentation on Events on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx

Comment: @Dante: Read up on event handling. You handle events by attaching a handler method (which is just like a regular method, but with a special signature) to that event. Whenever the event is raised, your handler method is called.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Closing event of the window for that.

Some more info
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closing.aspx

Comment: ahaa that starts to make some more sense now. thank you for that link.